# rails paperclip - changing aspect ratio of uploaded image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using paper clip, how can I change the aspect ratio of uploaded image.

Which is easier? Doing with jcrop or paperclip ?

I think paperclip would be nice but not sure where/how to keep the config options.

Comment: Would be nice if you accept correct answers. Looking at your profile I noticed you usually don't do that. Use green tick-mark to do so.

Comment: Sure, I will do that. In the last question, the correct answer was deleted for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

As for the paperclip you can easy do this by specifying convert options directly in your model. For example:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                  :preserve_files => true,
                  :styles => { :medium => "800x800>",
                               :small => "300x300>",
                               :thumb => "150x150>" },
                  :convert_options => { :medium => "-quality 70 -interlace Plane -strip",
                                        :small => "-quality 70 -interlace Plane -strip",
                                        :thumb => "-quality 70 -interlace Plane -strip" },
                  :default_url => "/images/missing.png"
```

you can use that way any ImageMagick's conver option.

All supported options are described [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php).

BTW: if you want it to be processed in background than add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'delayed_paperclip'
gem 'daemons'
```

and this to the model:

```
process_in_background :photo, queue: 'paperclip_processing'
```

to run/stop a daemon:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job -n 2 start
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job stop
```

and to see the progress and manage the queue this is great:

```
gem 'delayed_job_web'
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

[You'll need to use ImageMagick](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#image-processor) to get Paperclip to crop images. Paperclip only handles the upload process - it doesn't crop or store the images for you

---

I would recommend looking at how to use [Paperclip with ImageMagick](http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-install-image-magick-and-setup-paperclip), and then you'll have to find a way to populate your models' `styles` option with [ImageMagick commands](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/):

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "[[imagemagick code]]" }
```

[ImageMagick change aspect ratio without scaling the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518561/imagemagick-change-aspect-ratio-without-scaling-the-image)